# SQL Between Alphanumeric Values

Tags: db2

I have an alphanumeric column in my DB2 table. I'm searching for results that fall between two user entered values.

**Sample Data**

```
ABC300
ABC2002
CDEF200
ABC429
UOH250
```

**Sample SQL Query**

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM TABLE
WHERE VALUE BETWEEN 'ABC200' AND 'ABC700'
```

**Returned Values**

```
ABC300
ABC2002
ABC429
```

ABC2002 is an unwanted result. I understand why the query is returning this result. It's doing a string comparison and sees that "ABC2" falls between "ABC200" and "ABC700" and stops the comparison.

I know about PATINDEX but I'm using DB2 and there is no equivalent.

I've tried using TRANSLATE like this:

```
WHERE TRANSLATE(LOWER(VALUE), '', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') 
    BETWEEN TRANSLATE(LOWER('ABC200'), '', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    AND TRANSLATE(LOWER('ABC700'), '', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

And like this:

```
WHERE TRANSLATE(LOWER(VALUE), '', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') 
    BETWEEN 200 AND 700
```

And neither give desirable results.

The alphabetic prefix is not a fixed value or fixed length.

Any ideas? Thank you.

**EDIT**

Ok after explaining the problem here I was able to solve it (See: Rubber Duck Debugging). Here is what I did to solve my issue:

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM TABLE
WHERE TRIM(TRANSLATE(VALUE, '', ' 0123456789')) 
    BETWEEN TRIM(TRANSLATE(UPPER(@VALUE_HI), '', ' 0123456789')) 
    AND TRIM(TRANSLATE(UPPER(@VALUE_LO), '', ' 0123456789')) 
AND TRIM(TRANSLATE(VALUE, '', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')) 
    BETWEEN INT(TRIM(TRANSLATE(UPPER(@VALUE_LO), '', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))) 
    AND INT(TRIM(TRANSLATE(UPPER(@VALUE_HI), '', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')))
```

Comment: You may want to show what results you get from your attempts (using the same sample data) and indicate why they are undesirable.

Comment: Can you explain why `ABC2002 is an unwanted result`? Would it still be an `unwanted result` if the inputs were **"ABC100"** and "ABC700"? And what does `PATINDEX` have to do with this? That seems like a messy way to get the results that you indicated (though it's not quite clear what you want).

Comment: I want accounts that start with the prefix ABC and have the account number between 200 and 700. While researching an answer for this I saw several posts mentioning `PATINDEX` as a workaround.

Comment: Please removed "Solved" from your title and post the solution you found as a proper answer.

Comment: Side note: if the alphabetic prefix is different for the upper and lower bounds, the "solved" query will return a non contiguous range.  That is, if the bounds are `'ABC100'` and `'ABD900'`, it skips everything between `'ABC900'` and `'ABD100'`.  If the prefix is supposed to be the same, use regular `=`.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want this functionality, you should split this column into two separate columns.**  A character column should store the prefix, and a numeric column the number.

The problem here is that you need to perform two different comparison operations:

- A string comparison on the prefix.
- A numeric comparison on the numeric portion.

You can't squeeze both of these things out of a single comparison.

You should probably change the underlying data permanently, if possible.  The problem arises because you are storing two pieces of information (a category and a rank) in a single field, which goes against good database design.

But even if you can't, this is still the right approach: use a subquery to generate the two fields.

```
with col_split as (
    select
          translate(value, '', '1234567890') prefix,
          cast(translate(lower(value), '', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') as int) number
       from table
)
select * 
   from col_split
   where 
      prefix = 'ABC' and
      number between 200 and 700
```